# Importing external data to a SQL table to request a result

Tags: sql-server

Salutations,
I am currently trying to pull tag data (ASCII string) from a transaction managing software (softing 56eATManager) to an SQL table (SQL Server 2014) I currently have created. I need the data that I import to SQL to then export a ZPL (zebra printing language) back to the transaction manger and subsequently back to the PLC that the string originated from. The transaction manager is current mapped to the same server that the database is in.

This is in the SQL currently with  errors on a few different lines:

```
use [DATABASE]

declare @workorderID varchar(max)
declare @ZPLcallup varchar(max)

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <Softing tManager>
WITH
(   LOCATION                = <172.16.0.213> 
,   PUSHDOWN                  = ON
,   TYPE                      = BLOB_STORAGE
);
```

This is the list of errors I am getting:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'EXTERNAL'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Replace `<172.16.0.213>` with `'172.16.0.213'`and `<Softing tManager>` and with `[Softing tManager]`. Then try again.

Comment: Hey Aedvald Tseh, thanks for the response. I gave that a shot and I am getting my first errors on the syntax related to the CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE portion of my code.     Cheers